# display grid item position number in a grid observable collection

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Below is my item template in a grid view.

```
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNumber}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontSize="25"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="." VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="25" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="20" Height="100" Width="150"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageUri,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

what i am trying to achieve is to display the item position in the collection in the TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNumber} (if this were to be a list view, it would be row number), please how do i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define a class with the specific properties and bind it on xaml.

I made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding oc}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNumber}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontSize="25"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="." VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="25" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="20" Height="100" Width="150"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding source,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> oc { get; set;}
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        oc = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        oc.CollectionChanged += Oc_CollectionChanged;
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            oc.Add(new Test() {SerialNumber=i,source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/test.png")) });
        }
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Oc_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            for (int i =e.OldStartingIndex; i<oc.Count;i++)
            {
                oc[i].SerialNumber = i;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Test:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _SerialNumber;
    public int SerialNumber
    {
        get { return _SerialNumber; }
        set
        {
            _SerialNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SerialNumber");
        }
    }

    private BitmapImage _source;
    public BitmapImage source
    {
        get { return _source; }
        set
        {
            _source = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("source");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Xavier Xie , does the solution u provided help update the observablecollection row numbers when ever an item is removed from the observable collection? if it does not, any idea on how to make it to.

Comment: If you removed items, you need to update the `SerialNumber` by yourself. Please see my updated reply. I registered `CollectionChanged ` event to update the SerialNumber and I make the `Test` class inherit from [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). It's used to notify the UI that SerialNumber has been updated.